# How can I show the value of navigation property in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

[CategoryName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KapLq.png)

Index method:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)  
{  
   var data = objContext.Products.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 1);  
   return View(data);  
}
```

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yEsa.png)

Comment: add your poco of `product` class.

Answer (score 1):

if in your `product` poco, you have a navigation property for `Category` of `Product`, simply use:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => model.Category.Title)
```

assuming your product and category are as follow:

```
public class Product {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    // and other properties

    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCategory {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and in your map definition for `product` you have :

```
internal class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product> {
    public ProductMap () {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Properties, for example
        this.Property(t => t.ProductName )
            .HasMaxLength(200);
        // Table Mappings
        this.ToTable("Product");

        //Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.ProductCategory)
            .WithMany(t => t.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CategoryId );

    }
}
```